# Problemas con for each laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

lo que quiero es sumar dias por ejemplo en mi variable $diferencia me tira un valor de la fecha que traigo y lo que quiero es hacer un for que me recorra esos valores por ejemplo si me sale 2 en $diferencia que me sume el case 1 y el case 2  y me sume la cantidad de dias que le indico en un switch y que me lo almacene en una variable

este es el error que me tira 
message Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

esta es mi funcion

```
 public static function dias_pendientes($id){


        $fecha_actual= Carbon::now();

        $vigencia = Empleado::select('vigencia')->where('id', $id)->first()->vigencia;

        $fechaVigencia = Carbon::parse($vigencia);

        $diferencia = $fechaVigencia->diffInYears($fecha_actual);

        $dias=0;

        foreach ($diferencia as $diferencia) {

            switch ($diferencia) {

                case 1:

                    $dias=$dias+15;

                    break;

                case 2:

                    $dias=$dias+18;

                    break;

                case 3:

                    $dias=$dias+22;

                    break;


                default:

                    $dias=$dias+30;

                    break;

            }



        }

        return $dias;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero de todo, asegurate de que lo que almacenas en esa variable es un array o un objeto, porque el error que te da suena a que el argumento que se le pasa a ese loop corresponde a otro tipo de elemento (por ejemplo, si fuese una cadena, numero, etc.. no tendría sentido que se recorra con ningún tipo de bucle).

Pero al margen de esto, te recomiendo que cambies esto:

```
foreach ($diferencia as $diferencia) {
```

ya que al llamar a cada uno de los elementos que componen dicho objeto/array con el mismo nombre, no solo "estas confundiendo a PHP", sino que esto también podría contribuir a que tú mismo te equivoques. Además, me atrevería a decir que eso no puede ser considerado como "buenas practicas".

Cualquier otro nombre de variable te servirá. Por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($diferencia as $data) {
```

o bien

```
foreach ($diferencia as $dif) {
```

Así, dentro de tu bucle puedes distinguir en todo momento la variable "diferencia" (la cual contiene todos los índices/atributos/valores... que componen dicho array u objeto) de cada uno de los índices/atributos/valores que la componen.